# Svn unable to connect to a repository at url with wifi, perfectly working with hotspot

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I used TortoiseSVN some years ago for a while with a local repository.
In the last week I have installed the latest version but I'm having trouble to use it with my desktop PC and my home wifi, I mean that if I try to do a checkout with my desktop PC using my home wifi I get the error "unable to connect to a repository", while everything is perfectly working if I use my desktop PC and a mobile hotspot and it is perfectly working if I use my notebook and my home wifi.
In both cases I use Hamachi to connect to a VPN and access to the server.
I ave tried to checkout using command line and I get the error e170013.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was actually very easy (and stupid): my network was public, I changed it in private and it works.
I hope to help someone